# Android Cipher decode data

Tags: android, cryptography, encryption

I need to decrypt 6 MB byte[].

```
Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTS/NoPadding");
// Initialize cipher
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
doFinal(data);
```

This code works fine on my Galaxy 2 but when I'm running it on HTC legend that has only 16mb of heap
I'm getting OutOfMemory exception.

So I decided to split my data to chunks but probably I'm doing something wrong because this code doesn't work. Can you please help me to find what I'm doing wrong?

```
byte[] result = null;

      while (data.length> offset )
      {               
         concatenateByteArrays(result, cipher.update(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, offset, offset+MB)));      
         offset+=MB;
      }
 return  concatenateByteArrays(result,cipher.doFinal());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data length is not a multiple of MB, I think your code will forget to process a piece of data.
This version works correctly (sorry if my code is not concise but I hope is clear):

```
int inputLen = cipher.getBlockSize();
int inputOffset = 0;
byte[] output;
ByteArrayOutputStream outputArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

while(inputOffset + inputLen < input.length) {
    output = cipher.update(input, inputOffset, inputLen);
    inputOffset += inputLen;
    outputArray.write(output);
}

output = cipher.doFinal(input, inputOffset, input.length - inputOffset);
outputArray.write(output);
byte[] result = outputArray.toByteArray();
```